# 127.0.0.1 Redirected You too many times - Moodle 3.7

Tags: moodle

I am installing moodle 3.7, I get passed the minimum requirements but then i get the error too many redirects. I have tried clearing the moodledata folder a couple of times as well as clear the cache and session folders but it still gives me the same error. 
I have also tried clearing the browser cookies but still get the same error. Anyone with suggestions on how to get around this issue??

Moodle should normally finish the installation process without the recurrence of this error.

Comment: I think this about the issue with your config.php file, Please recheck your config settings.

Comment: Hello. how so. I have been using the same settings before